# difficulty in dynamically adding a div after another existing div

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to do a dot slider same as the one in this [image: img]. But I'm having difficulty getting it. [demo](http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com//bit-torrent/1276245126/demo_1.html).

Here is the html code

```
<div id="demo3" class="webwidget_slideshow_dot">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1" title="Sky"><img src="images/img_1.png" width="517" height="343" alt="slideshow_large"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="link2" title="Sea"><img src="images/img_2.png" width="517" height="343" alt="slideshow_large"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="link3" title="Flower"><img src="images/img_3.png" width="517" height="343" alt="slideshow_large"/></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the script

```
function init(){
        x.find("ul:first").wrap('<div class="slides_box"></div>');
        x.css("width",q).css("height",r);
        x.find(".slides_box").css("width",q).css("height",r);
        x.find("ul:first").width(parseInt(q)*y);
        x.find("ul:first").children("li").css("width",q).css("height",r);
        x.find("ul:first").children("li").children("a").children("img").css("width",q).css("height",r);
        x.find('#demo3').after('<div class="title_thumb_box"></div>');
        x.find(".title_thumb_box").append('<div class="title_box"></div>');
        x.find(".title_thumb_box").append('<div class="thumb_box"></div>');
        x.find(".title_thumb_box").css("background-color",sf);
 }
```

In the script, `<div class="slides_box"/>` dynamically wraps the list. Then `<div class"title_thumb_box">` is added after the `div class='slides_box'`. Thats the reason dots are displayed inside the container.

I'm trying to add it after the `<div id="demo3"/>`. When I tried I couldn't.
I'm trying to get the dots displayed outside the slide container "#demo3" so that I can add borders to the container as in the img.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HLVq/3)

Comment: In the linked demo, I get three errors: `Unexpected token <`, `jQuery is not defined`, and `$ is not defined`. This leads me to believe that you are not loading jQuery.

Comment: In the fiddle, I'm getting `p is not defined`. Please check your code for the definition of `p`.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle, so that the images also shows up.

Comment: @Rob W -- Thanks, but I want the dots outside the container as in the image above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add the .title_thumb_box outside the #demo3 container.

For this, just change the line:

`x.find('#demo3').after('<div class="title_thumb_box"></div>');`

to

`x.find('.slides_box').after('<div class="title_thumb_box"></div>');`

This will add the .title_thumb_box after the #demo3 div.

Comment: It should have right. I too thought so and tried that. Its not working. Its not totally displaying the dots. I couldn't figure out y? you can c the demo here http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com//bit-torrent/1276245126/demo_1.html

Comment: Ok, can you revert it back. I think its because the CSS used applies to classes within the slides_box div

Comment: though css didn't get applied I must be able to see the dynamically added <div> tags. But it doesn't show up in the markup

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that, weird